# Geometric data visualization does not lead to correct value representation.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Sorry for the vague title, but I have an issue regarding a custom data visualization which I couldn't describe better. I am stuck now.

My use case is that I have ordinal rating data (let's say an Amazon rating between 1 and 5), which is encoded through lines with same length and with a specific angle depending on the value of the rating. In my case the formula for the angle is as follows:

$$angle =  \frac{\pi * (5 - rating - 2))} {5}$$

Now in the following example I have **six 5-star** ratings and **three 1-star** ratings.

[Here is an image of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhpMw.png)

In the output, you can see the end location of the red line (which is the set of the 9 ratings) is located at the wrong location for the average, which would be 3.66. The yellow line shows the average based on the end location of my line. And the green line shows the true location of the average.

My question is now that I would like to understand mathematically why this is the case and if anybody knows a solution for me to edit the graph in a way that the final line location provides information about the average value.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a wrong formula.

Starting data:

$minRating= 1$

$maxRating = 5$

$initialAngle= \theta$

The "increment angle" between ratings must take a value $\beta=\frac{ratingRange}{totalSteps}$ and it must be that $\theta + totalSteps·\beta <= \pi$

Your visualizaton is a linear equation:
$$angle\;\; \alpha=\theta + \beta·numberOfSteps$$
where $numberOfSteps$ is the "rating", being it an integer number or not. I used "steps" so you can understand it better checking some integer ratings.

The formula you need is:
$$angle\;\; \alpha=\theta + \beta·rating$$

Let's say you have $maxRating - minRating = totalSteps= 4$ This hint allows us to say $beta < \pi/4$.

The point is to choose the angles $\theta, \beta$ so as the visualization gets clear. 
Let's choose some intial angle $\theta=\pi/6 \;$ (30 degrees) and also $\beta=\pi/6$

For the case $rating =0$ the visualized angle is 30 degrees.

For $rating =1$ the angle is 30+30·1=60 degrees.

For $rating =5$ the angle is 30+30·5=180 degrees.

Nope. We'd like some more simetry, not reaching 180 degrees.

Lets's try again with $\theta=0$ and $\beta=\pi/6$

$rating=0$ then angle is 0 degrees.

$rating=1$ then angle is 0+30·1= 30 degrees.

$rating=5$ then angle is 0+30·5= 150 degrees.

Much better. Then:
$$angle\;\; \alpha=\theta + \beta·rating = 0 + \pi/6·rating = \frac{\pi·rating}{6}$$

If you have ratings "5, 5, 3" then the average is 13/3=4.3. When putting this value in the formula we have $angle = \pi · 4.3 / 6 = 2.27\, rad = 130\, degrees \;$ which is below the angle for rating=5 (150) and greater than angle for rating=4 (120 degrees), as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, I still have a wrong end location of the line ([have a look at the output now](https://imgur.com/7jkcJku)). I just adjusted my initial angle = $0.5*\pi$ to be in eastward direction

Comment: [Here is a more complete visual](https://imgur.com/gallery/wLx8efB) to explain that my thinking of _end position = average_ is wrong. In this example there was a rating of 3, 5, 4, and 1 which would result in an average of 3.25. But the location of the last node of the red line is more likely located at 3.5. I would like to understand why

Comment: @JoeBe Your last link is broken. I've edited my answer (fixed some values) and added an example with an average. I don't know if you are using my formula or not; and if the fail is in the visualization code or in the maths.

Comment: Oh sorry, [here is the correct link](https://imgur.com/juKLVrP). The bottom example's end location of the red line of ratings is not at the true average's line location (black line). So I think there is a misunderstanding here. I do know how to create the average line. My problem is that this line does not allign with the end location of the whole path (which it should to read the graph correctly) And I would like to understand why, and if possible what I can do against this

Comment: @JoeBe Now I'm completely lost, I don't understand what you want. Is it a evolution graphic? What x,y axis mean? What is the arc for?

Comment: Ok. So I want to create a special and unique data viz chart. I came up with the idea described above that each data instance is encoded as a line with a specific angle. Now I would like to provide a sense of comparability for the user. For this I want to add a axis (the arc) that acts just like an axis in a line chart for instance. However, when I grow my path (the global red line) it seems that the final location of the chart is actually not representing the average value of the dataset. It does so in the top example in the above link but not in the second example on the bottom.

Comment: I think this is a very different question. It would be better if you delete this an open a new one. Add examples (different graphics, even done by hand) for 1 rating, 2 ratings,...5 ratings. And explain how the average should be drawn in each example.

Comment: OK. [I just did](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3371448/why-does-the-end-location-of-my-line-not-represent-the-average-of-the-data). I hope it is more clear now. But anyways thanks for your help!