# Why does the end location of my line not represent the average of the data?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I have a data viz that encodes ordinal data as a line of a specific angle. All the lines are chained together to create a path.

Here is an example
[image]

where I encode Amazon ratings in the range of $[1..5]$. You can see that in the first 2 examples the end node of the path is located at the angle from the focal point that represents the average of the data. This is what I want!

However, in the last example on the bottom, this is not the case anymore. The real average would be $3.25$ but the actual end node of the path is located around the angle representing $3.5$.

My question is, why this is the case and whether or not there is a solution to this problem. I would like to add an average line and axis (like the arc in the sample case) to add a cue for the user. But if the chart does not represent correct values I cannot do that.

Comment: Why would you expect the end point to represent the average? If you have an arbitrary sequence consisting of any number of 5’s and 1’s, the the endpoint can only be a 5 or a 1, which can’t really be the average (unless they were all 5’s or all 1’s).

Comment: @MPW That is true. I actually have implemented the graph in a way that [1 and 5 are not opposite angles](https://imgur.com/a/ND0eXvZ). So if I have for instance a sequence of [1,1,5,5] the final location would be at an angle representing a rating of 3, which indeed is the average.

Answer (score 1):

Let’s use standard radian measure for the angles (not your 0-5) and suppose each segment has length 1. If the angles are $t_1, t_2, \ldots, t_n$ for the $n$ ratings, and the path starts at $(0,0)$, then the endpoint $(x,y)$ has
$$x=\cos t_1+\cos t_2+\cdots +\cos t_n$$ and
$$y=\sin t_1+\sin t_2+\cdots +\sin t_n$$
so the ending angle $t$ satisfies
$$\tan t =\frac{\sin t_1+\sin t_2+\cdots +\sin t_n}{\cos t_1+\cos t_2+\cdots +\cos t_n}$$
so
$$t =\boxed{\arctan \frac{\sin t_1+\sin t_2+\cdots +\sin t_n}{\cos t_1+\cos t_2+\cdots +\cos t_n}}$$
But just averaging the angles instead would give
$$t’ = \boxed{\frac{t_1 +t_2+\cdots+ t_n}{n}}$$
These are not the same thing.

Comment: mh... ok. so I just thought about this very wrong the whole time... nevertheless I might found a tweak that makes the chart look the way I want it. After each iteration I check the location of the angle that represents the current average and adjust the current rating's line length in a way that it touches the average line. This way my end node will always be loacted at the true average angle.